# Adding user in the Image (using Ubuntu Customization Kit)

Tags: 12.04, uck

I am using **Ubuntu Customization Kit** to customize Ubuntu 12.04.

I created a user by #useradd command at the time of creating image and bundled it. After installing that bundled OS it shows that user but unable to login, giving the password it again returns to the login screen.

Can someone let me know correct way of adding a user in that image and bundle it.

Comment: Can you login to your customized OS as a guest user? If you can login as a guest user and the customized OS is running OK, then you can try resetting the password of the user you created at the time of creating the image, which is not hard to do from an Ubuntu live DVD or live USB. Otherwise if you can't login at all then the login loop is your problem, and there is a different way of solving that.

Comment: i think the problem is while creating user inside image it creates /home/user while installing that OS it takes as a fresh OS where there is no home directory for that user. Is that the reason y its not logging in.. If yes can u help me resolve this karel

Answer (score 2):

Whatever user you created at the time of creating the image, the Ubuntu installer apparently ignored it, because it didn't create a `/home` directory for that user. So apparently you have just one regular user on that system, and that is the user you created when you were installing the customized Ubuntu OS and you also should be able to login without a password as a guest user.

While installing the customized OS, the Ubuntu installer asked you to type your user name so that it could create a `/home` directory for a new user with that user name. Then it asked you to type a password for that user or else if you left the password field blank you can login without a password just by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

If for some reason, the Ubuntu login screen does not accept your password for the new user that you created in the Ubuntu installer, then you can change the password for that user from an Ubuntu live DVD or live USB. The login password is normally the same (by default) as the administrative password which is used to run `sudo` commands in Ubuntu. The instructions for resetting the administrative password are found in the answers to this question: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).