# How to Install Okular on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, okular

Can some please let me how to Install Okular on Ubuntu 12.04 and also KParts Plugin by command prompt or if you can please let me know any ppa's to install it

Already tried

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kalakris/okular
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install okular
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
okular:Depends: libkio5 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libkparts4 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libkprintutils4 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libokularcore4 (= 4:4.13.2-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libphonon4 (>= 4:4.7.0really4.3.80) but it is not     installable
       Depends: libpoppler-qt4-3 (>= 0.18) but it is not installable
       Depends: libqca2 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
       Depends: libqimageblitz4 (>= 1:0.0.4) but it is not installable
       Depends: phonon but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Let me know what needs to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Okular 0.15 on 12.04 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172126/how-to-install-okular-0-15-on-12-04-lts)

Comment: @Private Please review the accepted answer to your linked question. The instructions in the accepted answer to your linked question were what were causing the unmet dependencies in this question, so this question is not a duplicate of your linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both okular and kpartsplugin are in the Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 12.04, so you didn't need to add the two PPAs to install them. If you don't need the two PPAs for any other reason they can be removed, and then just install okular and kpartsplugin in the usual way.

From the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:kalakris/okular
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install okular kpartsplugin
```

Comment: No kpartsplugin package
should i edit something in apt sourcelist?

sudo apt-get install kpartsplugin
sudo: unable to resolve host SharathRL-PES
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kpartsplugin

Comment: kpartsplugin is in the universe repository. Search for Software Sources in the Dash and make sure that the **universe** repository is enabled in your list of software sources. From the terminal run `sudo apt-get update` to update your list of available packages. Then you should be  able to install kpartsplugin in the usual way.

Comment: Great, btw always search for the package you want to install in the Ubuntu Software Center first, even if some tutorial on the web said to add a PPA.

Comment: karel i am trying to build a image.. There in that I cannot access software centre. PPA was giving lot of dependencies issue.. anyways thanks..
Can u help me with this question if u r free buddy

http://askubuntu.com/questions/522762/adding-user-in-the-image-using-ubuntu-customization-kit